# angularjs - cant access form object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with form in AngularJS. I need to make custom validation. but I cannot access the form or the `$error` object in template (or controller) in order to achieve this.
I did this previously in other projects and it always worked. I managed to find out, that the form is in some weird state. I tried to show its contents in the template and it did not work. When I call the form myForm and write `{{myForm}}` somewhere in HTML, I expect to see something like this:

> {"$error":{},"$name":"myForm","$dirty":false,"$pristine":true,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$submitted":false,"user":{"$viewValue":"John
>   Doe","$modelValue":"John
>   Doe","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$name":"user","$options":null},"email":{"$viewValue":"john.doe@gmail.com","$modelValue":"john.doe@gmail.com","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$name":"email","$options":null}}

However, in current project, I see this:

```
{"user":{},"email":{}}
```

Why is it so `minified`?

here is the full source code as example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>  
<body>

<h2>Validation Examplea</h2>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" 
name="myForm" novalidate>

<p>Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="user" ng-model="user" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.user.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
</span>
</p>

<p>Email:<br>
<input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
<span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
<span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
</span>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit"
ng-disabled="myForm.user.$dirty && myForm.user.$invalid ||  
myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
</p>
{{myForm}}
</form>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = 'John Doe';
    $scope.email = 'john.doe@gmail.com';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In my code, I see this:

```
{"user":{},"email":{}}
```

In online editor, I see this:

```
{"$error":{},"$name":"myForm","$dirty":false,"$pristine":true,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$submitted":false,"user":{"$viewValue":"John Doe","$modelValue":"John Doe","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$name":"user","$options":null},"email":{"$viewValue":"john.doe@gmail.com","$modelValue":"john.doe@gmail.com","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[null],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$name":"email","$options":null}}
```

The example is from this site: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Comment: We would need to see a working example to be able to determine the issue

Comment: Have you made sure the name attribute has been assigned on the form tag in your HTML?

Comment: I copied the source code from w3 tutorial about form validation. It worked in other app, also on w3 online editor, but the same code did not work on my project. Looks like it is some settings or what...
later I found out, that angular xeditable form works slightly different than basic form in angular and I am using xeditable form.
however, when I tried basic simple form in my project, it still wasnt right. I could access the form properties like $error and so on, but the whole form dump was impossible in template. Weird.